# Lasting discrepancy between the site command and indexed pages in Google Webmaster

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I have recently uploaded a blog on blogger. The pages of my blog are accessible for crawling and indexing and I can see that some crawling has started two weeks ago.

I have noticed that the information available on Google Webmaster's Indexed Pages is updated only once a week. I have used the site command to get information faster.

Here is my issue:

- For more than a week, the site command returns about 181 results.
- The Indexed Status said 0 URL indexed, 126 ever crawled, 404 not selected, 2559 blocked by robots
- I am receiving diverse small traffic for about 6 pages only
- Today the Index Status information was updated, but it remained the same as last week

Why doesn't google mention that at least some of my pages have been indexed? Should I wait longer? Thanks.

**P.S.**: Even stranger, when I go in Search Queries > Top Pages, I see 98 pages... How come? What should I believe?

Comment: "site command returns about 181 results" - for me, `site:find-word.blogspot.co.uk` returns no results!?

Comment: mmmm, interesting... I found out I could add atom based sitemaps in Google Webmaster. I am trying this now... (may be you can try .nl since this is where I created them)

Comment: Ah yes... `site:find-word.blogspot.com` (note: `.com`) does indeed return 183 results. Since I'm in the UK, it seems that blogspot automatically redirects me to the `.co.uk` version of your site (which I then copied to do the site search). `.nl` does not return any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait longer.  In the past, it has taken about 3 months before all the crawling / indexing / page changes settle down.  I have also found it never/ rarely lists all your pages as indexed.

Try some Google searches for content on some of your pages.  You may see them showing up in results sooner than they are listed as indexed in Webmaster Tools.

Comment: I have added some atom sitemaps via Google Webmaster (see post on my blog: http://www.tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/12/how-to-importindex-large-blogs-on.html) and it accelerates the indexing process.